# 12.04 Ubuntu - Sharing Wireless Internet Connection with Freesat through ethernet!

Tags: 12.04

I'm trying to share my Ubuntu's 12.04 (Desktop) wireless (wlan0) internet connection with a Freesat box through ethernet (eth0).

I've set up the wired connection IPv4 settings "Share with other computers" and I'm getting a wired connection but unfortunately the Freesat box can't seem to automatically configure the network settings.

Available Manual Network Settings (Freesat Box):

IP Address,
Subnet Mask,
Router Address,
DNS Address

If I try to configure the freesat box manually will I need to configure the wired (eth0) settings differently in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

From http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=157&t=102779&start=0

I just spent the better part of the day getting Internet Connection Sharing via Network Manager to work on Maya. The problem is that my installation didn't have a /etc/resolv.conf. If you're connecting via DHCP, you don't need one, but apparently Network Manager's Internet Connection Sharing does.

So do "sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf" and (assume you get a blank file) enter in this, replacing the bracketed items of course:

```
domain [YourDomain]
nameserver [YourPrimaryNameserver]
nameserver [YourSecondaryNameserver]
```

You can get the primary and secondary nameserver IPs by right-clicking on Network Manager and selecting "Connection Information" and making sure you're on the tab for your Internet connected network device.

As soon as I made my resolv.conf and rebooted, the device I was sharing found the Internet with no problem as all.